# Energy band diagram for solid state: what is the meaning of $k$?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am having trouble with the meaning of the $k$ vectors in an energy diagram.
If I want to populate some band, let say using a laser, what will be the significance of $k$?
Does it correspond to the polarization angle with respect to particular planes?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the wave vector. See the [Wikipedia article on band structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure) or [these lecture notes](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~jarrell/COURSES/SOLID_STATE/Chap7/chap7.pdf) for some explanations. If something is still unclear after going through the basics, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Thanks. It is quite abstract as thinking of wave vector. I wanted to understand how can I populate a specific band at some k location with light. And what is the meaning of k=0 these states are not allowed for particle in a box because of the uncertainty principle ..